# Return status from true to false after edit in .Net Core

Tags: asp.net-core, repository-pattern, asp.net-core-identity

I am using .Net Core 5

I have an example: The post status would be True: Approved and False: Pending.

When I post a post and is approved, I want to edit my post and then force it back to False: Pending.

So what is the solution here? Can you help me?

I will update my code below:

**Submit Article**

```
public ArticleFacultyViewModel SubmitArticle(ArticleFacultyViewModel articleFacultyViewModel)
    {
        var doesArticleExists = _dbContext.Articles.Include(a => a.Faculty)
            .Where(a => a.Title == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title &&
                        a.Faculty.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId);

        if (doesArticleExists.Any())
        {
            // Message
        }
        else
        {
            var activeSemester = _semesterRepository.GetActiveSemester();
            var articleResult = _dbContext.Articles.Add(articleFacultyViewModel.Article);
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            _semesterRepository.AddArticleSemester(articleResult.Entity.Id, activeSemester.Id);
            return null;
        }

        var model = new ArticleFacultyViewModel
        {
            Article = articleFacultyViewModel.Article,
            Faculties = _dbContext.Faculties.ToList(),
            StatusMessage = "Error: Article already exists in " + _dbContext.Faculties
                .SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId).FacultyName.ToString()
        };

        return model;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> The Article's status is authorized by me to my manager, they will take
> overview and Approve (True) for it or Decline (False) in the Deltail
> view of that Article. The default of Article when submitted is False

It seems that you want to change the article status in the EditArticle method, right? If that is the case, after finding the existing article from the database, you could change the status, then, call the SaveChanges() method to save changes, After that, you should also change the article status in the ArticleFacultyViewModel view model.

Try to refer the following steps to modify your code:

```
public ArticleFacultyViewModel EditArticle(ArticleFacultyViewModel articleFacultyViewModel)
    {
        var doesArticleExists = _dbContext.Articles.Include(a => a.Faculty)
            .Where(a => a.Title == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title &&
                        a.Faculty.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId);
        var articleInDb = GetArticleById(articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Id);
        if (doesArticleExists.Any() && articleInDb.Title != articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title)
        {
            //if find the exist article
            //change the article status.
            doesArticleExists.FirstOrDefault().status = true;
            //call the SaveChanges method to save changes.
            _dbContext.SaveChanges();             

            //change article's status in the ArticleFacultyViewModel     
            articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Status = true;


            // Message
        }
        else
        {
            articleInDb.Title = articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Title;
            articleInDb.Content = articleFacultyViewModel.Article.Content;

            _dbContext.SaveChanges();
            return null;
        }

        var model = new ArticleFacultyViewModel
        {
            Article = articleFacultyViewModel.Article,
            Faculties = _dbContext.Faculties.ToList(),
            StatusMessage = "Error: Article already exists in " + _dbContext.Faculties
                .SingleOrDefault(f => f.Id == articleFacultyViewModel.Article.FacultyId).FacultyName.ToString()
        };

        return model;
    }
```

Comment: @HuyNguyen, please check the updated content, after finding the existing article from the database, you could change the status, then, call the SaveChanges() method to save changes, After that, you should also change the article status in the ArticleFacultyViewModel view model.